# Can I say "yesterday's mathematics' teacher"

Tags: grammar, syntax

...or should I say "yesterday mathematics teacher"?

> EDIT

Usage in a full sentence:

'I'm waiting for yesterday's Mathematics' teacher to come online'

Comment: Can you provide its usage in a full sentence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

American here, so your usage might vary by country. I think it will be dependent on your intention.

```
Yesterday, the mathematics teacher taught algebra.
Yesterday's mathematics teacher taught algebra.
```

I think both are fine but mean different things. The first one means that the normal math teacher taught algebra yesterday. The second infers that there was a different teacher (substitute teacher possibly) yesterday that taught algebra.

In your example, I think this would be what you want to do:

```
I'm waiting for yesterday's mathematics teacher to come online.
```

Comment: Ok, so I can't really say "Mathematics' teacher" or for instanace "Philosophy's teacher"?

Comment: I don't think so. The apostrophe shows possession and math doesn't own the person. Also, I rarely hear mathematics; in conversation, math is far more common.

Comment: Ok, interesting. Is there a difference between the two?

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

The teacher who taught mathematics yesterday is "yesterday's mathematics teacher". The teacher who (now) teaches philosophy is the (current) philosophy teacher.

While a teacher may personify his discipline and say that he belongs to it, it would be unconventional. ;)